# Oracle Select Query Takes Too Much When Not In Clause Used

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

ORACLE VERSION : 19C

I am working on a legacy select query which returns around 60k rows. It İS formed of 9 joins and 2 unions. I want to exclude a small number of audience if they are inside the case i specified.
I wrote a select query using four joins and then used not in clause to exclude these audience.
The query was executing in aroung 15seconds before but after i wrote this not in clause it did not finish even in 20 minutes and i aborted it.

It is coded like this;

```
A.ID NOT IN (SELECT A.ID
         FROM A
         INNER JOIN B
         ON A.X = BX
         INNER JOIN C
         ON B.Y = C.Y
         INNER JOIN D
         ON C.Z = D.Z)
```

However if i execute this subquery before the select and insert it into a table and then use not in clause for the table it almost finishes in 15 seconds just as normal

It is coded like this;

```
A.ID NOT IN (SELECT GT.ID FROM GENERATED_TABLE GT)
```

Do you know why it takes too much time when it is not populated into a table?
And are there any way to make the first one run faster?

Expecting it to take much less time

Comment: did you run an explain plan and review the results?

Comment: I suspect there's an index on the generated table, but Oracle doesn't automatically index subqueries.

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes i run an explain plan but seems like the subquery doesnt affect too much

Comment: @Barmar i just created the table for testing and it is not indexed yet

Comment: 1. An old trick is to convert "not in" to an outer join and use something like "b.x is null" for the not-in condition.  Oracle often optimizes the join better than a not-in subquery.
2. the more tables participating in a query the more difficult it is for the execution engine to optimize. You had 9 joins = 10 tables and added 4 more, so you could have passed some threshold.  Not that it helps except to understand what might be happening here.

Comment: The three basic options are `NOT IN`, `OUTER JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS`. Often the query planner provides the same quer plan for all three but the only way to know for sure is to check the query plan. You say "seems like the subquery doesnt affect too much" It's hard to tell from this decscription if anything changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use EXISTS instead of IN statement. The EXISTS clause is much faster than IN when the subquery results is very large.

And again - check EXPLAIN PLAN and search for FULL SCAN keywords. That will be the main cause.